# FFMPEG -stream_loop from a .mp4 file displays a distorted output (virtual webcam/fake cam) Linux Mint

Tags: ffmpeg

Can someone please tell me why this command works with a .mkv file:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -re -i /home/roku33/Desktop/s.mkv -vcodec rawvideo -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video2
```

But when I switch the input file to s.mp4, it breaks and shows up distorted? I'm on Linux Mint. I assume it is a codec issue and I need to change the command. I am obviously a noob here but please know that I spent 14 hours to get this far yesterday, I have searched endlessly. I understand the answer is likely here somewhere.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Remove `-re`. You are deliberately feeding the input stream as slow as you can, making it the bottleneck. Instead, flood the v4l2 device with data so it'll always have data to show.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate you taking the time to both educate, and assist me. I was unaware, but have learned now about -re. That said reeeee, sorry could not help myself. I'm still getting errors I will attach a screen shot. Thanks again.

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/sKXWB0F/stackoverflow-ss.png - it won't let me add the image to my post.

Comment: Is `s.mp4` just a re-encoded version of `s.mkv`? Post `Input #0` log of both runs as well as the Output log of the mp4 case. The fact your buffer always gets the exact same amount of data appears to be something deliberate rather than buffer underflow issue that I originally thought.

Comment: Also, post the output of `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -list_formats all /dev/video2`.

Comment: my friend, I was able to fix it. I thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i /home/roku33/Desktop/a3.mp4 -vcodec rawvideo -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video2`

This is finally what ended up working.